# Extracting data from multipart/x-mixed-replace content-type

Tags: javascript, server-sent-events

If I do have the velow html5 element:

```html
<div>
    Counter: <span id="content"></span>
</div>
```

And my server is returning a counter, I can listen to this counter, and display it at the above element as:

```
var source = new EventSource("http://localhost:8080/counter");
   source.onmessage = function (event) {
   var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
   document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = counter;
}
```

But what if the server is sending me a `multipart/x-mixed-replace`, how can I receive it in the JavaScript code, and display its content in a `div` or 'object`or even`image`, the server is expected to send me multiple images that can be displayed as video streaming.

I saw [this](https://developpaper.com/using-multipart-x-mixed-replace-to-realize-http-real-time-video-streaming/) but could not understand how to do it in JavaScript at browser.

Pure JavaScript please.

Note: I was able to do it as:

```html
<object data="http://localhost:8080/camera" width="300" height="200" alt="Cam streaming"></object>
```

But I prefer using SSE (Server-Sent-Event) to do it.